# remove amount from price then insert new price

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i have a question. I have no idea how i need to insert a search in google for it so i'm going to ask it here.

I have like 50.00 euro.
in mysql table it is showed as

```
 Id | Username | Balance
 1  | Kev      | 50.00
```

Now when i buy something that is worth like lets say 5.00 euro
it would be 50.00 - 5.00 = 45.00 euro left on balance

```
 Id | Username | Balance
 1  | Kev      | 45.00
```

Now my question is. How do i do this with a  simply get old balance then insert the new balance into the table? Also i'm using PDO

Sorry for my nooby question but i have no idea how to insert this into a search  in google.

~Kev

Comment: query -> `UPDATE \`table\` SET \`Balance\` = \`Balance\`-5.00 WHERE \`Username\`='Kev'` or `WHERE \`Id\`=1`?

Comment: Why are we upvoting this? ^^^^^ Have we lost the plot

Comment: @Sean it worked. Could u make it a answer? so i can set it as finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a row by setting the column equal to the current column value minus (or plus) another value

```
UPDATE `table` SET `Balance` = `Balance`-5.00 WHERE `Username`='Kev'
```

or

```
UPDATE `table` SET `Balance` = `Balance`-5.00 WHERE `Id`=1
```